# how i can insert into database from checkbox in datalist using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black" style="margin-right: 260px" Width="720px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="questionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        A:
                        <asp:Label ID="answer1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answer1") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                        B:
                        <asp:Label ID="answer2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answer2") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
                        C:
                        <asp:Label ID="answer3Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answer3") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server"  />
                        D:
                        <asp:Label ID="answer4Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answer4") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
```

For example:

I want to insert `answer1labl` into column `student_answer` in database when: `checkbox1.checked == true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the button click, you can do like,

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");

            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                string text = ((Label)item.FindControl("answer1Label")).Text;

                //save code
            }
        }
    }
```